# Display user's profile in a lightbox

Tags: 7, users

When a user clicks on the "My Account" link I would like the user's profile to show up in a lightbox much like the admin menu overlay works.

I am using Drupal 7.

I am not sure how to do this. My first attempt was to render $user_profile and put it in a lightbox:

```
<div id="lightbox_this_div">
   <?php print render($user_profile); ?>
</div>
```

but $user_profile is not available in page.tpl.php

Any thoughts?

EDIT: To be clear I just want to lightbox the content of the user's profile along with the tabs and be able to style the page. So I am not looking to lightbox the entire /user page with the site headers in an iframe style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to "rel" tag in link.

```
<a href="/user" rel="lightframe[|width:400px; height:300px; scrolling: auto;]">My Account</a>
```

---

If you want show a specific region then use this.

```
<a href="/node/xxx #content-inner > *" rel="lightmodal[|width:700px;height:300px;]">Click to see only the content inside #content-inner</a>
```

---

Detailed tutorial can be found [here](http://drupal.org/node/144488)

Comment: But that will give me the whole page with the header. I just want the profile content

Comment: profile content including the tabs and I want to be able to style it.

Comment: i have updated answer. read again

Comment: Thanks, for those looking for more documentation on this it can be found here http://drupal.org/node/144488

Comment: You did an error "If you want show a specific region then use this."

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="/node/[nid] .content" rel="lightmodal">
<img src="image.jpg" />
</a>
```

That's the right way... on d.org some retard edited documentation and now it messed up